# Login with apple id in android returns invalid redirect_uri

Tags: android, spf, apple-sign-in

I am trying to integrate login with apple in android. Hence I am using a webView , and trying to loading the webView with the following url as per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/incorporating_sign_in_with_apple_into_other_platforms) . My url is following

```
https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?client_id=com.example.core.service&redirect_uri=https://example-staging.io/apple_login&response_type=code&scope=email&response_mode=form_post&state=initial
```

I have added `https://example-staging.io/apple_login` this url in return url in developer console, without `https` or any trailing slash .

And my service id is `com.example.core.service`

But I am still getting this error .

One this I am not sure , is it necessary to a `SPF` record of the domain?
Here one thing to mention is `example-staging.io` doesn't have any SPF record. Am I getting this error due to this ?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue found this link:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122536#381571

As per this link :

You are using the primary app's id (iOS app's ID) instead of the services ID. Since the primary app does not have any redirect URLs registered whereas the authorization request contains a redirect URL, it fails validation

Comment: You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your server is returning the same exact url as you defined in the apple developer dashboard.

I had the same issue and after 2 hours of struggle I found out that my server was returning `http` instead of `https`

Answer (score 0):

SPF is an anti-forgery mechanism for email. It has nothing at all to do with Apple ID logins, URLs, or redirects.

Comment: Thanks , but could you tell me , why does it happening ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea, but it’s not SPF!